# Generating playlist for jplayer in php

Tags: php, mp3, playlist, jplayer

i am actually working on this mentioned title. player show the list, its generating perfectly. but i am no where to make it actually play that file. i must be wrong some where.
i need advise fox. (ahh if i can attach the files.)

```
my class

    class DecodDir 
        {
            function getFiles($directory)
            {
                $all_files  = array();
                $handler    = opendir($directory);
                while($files=readdir($handler))
                {
                    if($files!="." && $files!="..")
                    {
                        $all_files[]= $files;
                    }
                }
                closedir($handler);
                return $all_files;
            }
        }

################# file where i am using this class *###############



 <?php

 include("decoddir.php");

 $obj       = new DecodDir();
 $results   = $obj->getFiles("mp3");
 $total     = count($results);
 $string        = "";
 for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){

    $string .="
        {
        name:'$results[$i]',
        mp3:'mp3/$results[$i]',
        ogg:'$results[$i]'
        },
        ";
 }

    ?>
// its at the top of that html file (ofcorse with the php ext)

and below, this is where it is generating the playlist

var audioPlaylist = new Playlist("2", [
<?php echo $string; ?>
],
```

http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02/ (the link from where i get jplayer) you can see the audio player with playlist.
(actually i don't know hot format the code in here stackoverflow)
thanks
Rafay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken the liberty of re-factoring the code a bit for you.  I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but it will help to have the beginnings of a better class on your side.

```
<?php

class DecodDir
{

    private
        $directory,
        $files;

    public function __construct( $directory = null )
    {
        if ( ! is_null($directory) )
        {
            $this->setDirectory( $directory );
        }
    }

    public function setDirectory( $directory )
    {
        $this->directory = $directory;
        $this->files = null;

        // TODO put some validation in here;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDirectory()
    {
        if ( is_null($this->directory) )
        {
            $this->directory = './';
        }
        return $this->directory;
    }

    private function getFiles()
    {
        if ( is_null($this->files) )
        {
            $this->files = array();
            $handler    = opendir( $this->getDirectory() );
            while($files=readdir($handler))
            {
                if($files!="." && $files!="..")
                {
                    $this->files[]= $files;
                }
            }
            closedir($handler);
        }

        return $this->files;
    }

    public function getJson()
    {
        $list = array();

        foreach ( $this->getFiles() as $filename )
        {
            $item = new stdClass();

            $item->name = $filename;
            $item->mp3 = "mp3/{$filename}";
            $item->ogg = $filename;

            $list[] = $item;
        }

        $json = json_encode( $list );

        return $json;

    }

    public function countFiles()
    {
        return sizeof( $this->getFiles() );
    }

}


$obj = new DecodDir( 'mp3' );
echo $obj->getJson();
```

Comment: $string  = $obj->getJson();
 $string  = str_replace("\\/", '/', $string); thats what i did to correct the path. and the modification you did has done a great job with my quest for generating the playlist and playing the song.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the code at the following site to do what you are trying to do, I think:

http://jplaylister.yaheard.us/

Sadly, it doesn't currently collapse a song stored in multiple formats (mysong1.mp3, mysong1.ogg) into one playlist item, but otherwise it is pretty feature-complete and has lots of customizable options.

Hope this helps!